# Issues separating my Plugin pages into different files

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, oop

As my last (first) plugin got a bit hard to manage with 6 admin pages in 1 file, I decided to split them up for this one, but I am getting nothing but issues doing so.

In my plugins functions file (LoadPressFunctions.php) I have this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'LoadPress', 'LoadPress', 'manage_options', 'LoadPressPlugin', 'LoadPress_Plugin', 'dashicons-download', 99  );
}

function LoadPress_Plugin() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    include 'LoadPressOptions-Home.php';
}
```

And in my LoadPressOptions-Home.php file I have this:

```
<?php
echo '<style>
    h1 {
        letter-spacing: 8px;
    }
    .sectionHeader {
        background-color: #E5E5E5;
        padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-left: 4px solid #2A333E;
    }
    .sectionNotification {
        background-color: #E5E5E5;
        padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
        margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
        border-left: 4px solid #ffce1f;
    }
    ul#adminmenu a.wp-has-current-submenu:after, ul#adminmenu>li.current>a.current:after {
        border-right-color: #12171C;
    }
  </style>';

    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h1>LoadPress</h1>';
    echo '<p class="description" id="tagline-description">Simplify Brilliance, Simplify Life.</p>';
    ?>
    <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="<?php echo admin_url() ?>admin.php?page=LoadPressPlugin">Home</a>
            <!--<a class="nav-tab" href="<?php echo admin_url() ?>admin.php?page=LoadPressPlugin-Settings">Settings</a>-->
            <a class="nav-tab" href="<?php echo admin_url() ?>admin.php?page=LoadPressPlugin-About">About/Credits</a>
            <a class="nav-tab" style="background-color: red;">Settings (Not available in Alpha)</a>
            <a class="nav-tab" href="<?php echo admin_url() ?>admin.php?page=LoadPressPlugin-Docs">Documentation</a>
            <a class="nav-tab" style="background-color: red;">Email Editor (Coming Soon)</a>
        </h2>
        <?php
//Options
    echo '<div>';
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>/wp-content/plugins/LoadPress/LoadPressLogo-Banner.png" style="margin-top: 10px;"/>
<?php
    echo '</div>';
?>
    <div class="sectionNotification">
    <h3>Thank You for choosing LoadPress</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="sectionHeader">
    <h3>What is LoadPress?</h3>
    <p>LoadPress is a professional plugin that allows site community members to post downloadable files, such as modifications, save files and other community applicable files.</p>
    <p>This plugin was developed for use primarily with modding communities for video games, and other video game related products, and uses a simplistic yet robust setup with several different fallbacks in case of mistakes.</p>
    <p>At the time of writing this, LoadPress is primarily used for in-house projects developed by Kyle Briggs & Don Briggs Ltd.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sectionHeader">
    <h3>Why LoadPress?</h3>
    <p>LoadPress is an excellent choice for targeted community functionality as it offers several things other plugins do not:</p>
    <ol>
        <li>It allows users to upload files in any format (settable by editing the plugin).</li>
        <li>It allows total administrative control over all files, but only gives regular users access to their own.</li>
        <li>It simplifies the Media section to only display a regular user's own media (admins can see all).</li>
        <li>It is the ONLY plugin currently available for Wordpress that offers this functionality tailored specifically to file-sharing, and works seamlessly with any SEO package.</li>
        <li>At the core, it runs on Wordpress' own API so the custom post type can be edited to your needs easily.</li>
    </ol>
    </div>

    </div>
    <?php
```

But I get a blank page now that I have moved this content from the main file to it's own one, no content loads from it.

If I replace the file content with:

```
<?php
echo '<h1>Hi</h1>';
```

Everything works fine, but I cannot see ANY syntax errors with the Home.php content as it was copied and pasted straight out the function (and added

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Have you enabled debugging in wordpress?

Open wp-config.php in the root wordpress folder and change this line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Your PHP errors will then output to the screen.

Comment: Nothing prints to the screen with this.

Comment: What happens if put a syntax error in your file? Does the syntax error show up?

Comment: Interestingly, No.

Comment: Okay, what is your hosting environment like?

Comment: Sorry, posted that prematurely. Are you hosting locally? Shared hosting or dedicated?

Comment: I am hosting through 1&1, so it would be shared